# Creating Haskell object of certain type (package: newsynth)

Tags: haskell, instantiation

basic Haskell question here. I'm trying to use newsynth's [Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newsynth-0.4.0.0/docs/Quantum-Synthesis-EuclideanDomain.html) to run the Euclidean algorithm, implemented there as `euclid_gcd`, in the ring of Gaussian integers `Z[i]`. Here's what I tried in GHCi:

```
Prelude> import Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain> import Quantum.Synthesis.Ring
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain Quantum.Synthesis.Ring> let p = Cplx 13 0
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain Quantum.Synthesis.Ring> let z = Cplx 5 1
Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain Quantum.Synthesis.Ring> euclid_gcd z p
```

The output is

```
<interactive>:12:1: error:
    • Non type-variable argument
        in the constraint: EuclideanDomain (Cplx a)
      (Use FlexibleContexts to permit this)
    • When checking the inferred type
        it :: forall a. (EuclideanDomain (Cplx a), Num a) => Cplx a
```

so I tried `Prelude Quantum.Synthesis.EuclideanDomain Quantum.Synthesis.Ring> :set FlexibleContexts` but this returned `Some flags have not been recognized: FlexibleContexts`. I think I need to somehow create elements specific to `ZComplex` but I'm not sure how to do that beyond just complex numbers with components in `Z`. Any guidance on how to do this is greatly appreciated.

I'd also be grateful for guidance on, more generally speaking, how to interpret documentation such as the one linked above and how to use it to instantiate elements of particular types/classes (I might not have used those words right, apologies if so).

Thanks!

Comment: It's `:set -XFlexibleContexts` in ghci. Not the most discoverable thing...

Comment: You can put ghci commands into a `.ghci` file that is run at startup https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-ghci-files

Comment: We see that your code is gradually pushed to the right of the lines and so out of sight by the long package names. To counter this, popular additions to the ${HOME}/.ghci file are: `:set prompt  " λ> "` and `:set prompt-cont  "|λ> "`

Comment: These are great, thank you all!